# Jquery datetimepicker text in format

Tags: jquery, datepicker, datetimepicker

I'm using Jquery's Datetimepicker in a reservation form for a Dutch restaurant. Works perfect, but one thing doesn't work.

Is it possible to have text between the date and time with Jquery datetimepicker?

Instead of this: Wednesday 15-10-2014 01:09

I want this: Wednesday 15-10-2014 **at** 01:09

```
    var logic = function( currentDateTime ){
    if( currentDateTime.getDay()==4 || currentDateTime.getDay()==5 || currentDateTime.getDay()==6 ){
        this.setOptions({
            maxTime:'22:31'
        });
    }else
        this.setOptions({
            maxTime:'17:31'
        });
};
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    onChangeDateTime:logic,
    onShow:logic,
    format: 'l d-m-Y H:i',
    step: 15,
    minTime: '11:00',

             beforeShowDay: function(day) {

            if (day.toDateString()===new Date(2014,8,11).toDateString()) {
          return ["xdsoft_disabled"]
      }
      if (day.toDateString()===new Date(2014,8,12).toDateString()) {
          return ["xdsoft_disabled"]
      }
      if (day.toDateString()===new Date(2014,8,13).toDateString()) {
          return ["xdsoft_disabled"]
      }
          if (day.toDateString()===new Date(2014,8,16).toDateString()) {
          return ["xdsoft_disabled"]
      }
          if (day.toDateString()===new Date(2014,8,17).toDateString()) {
          return ["xdsoft_disabled"]
      }
          if (day.toDateString()===new Date(2014,8,18).toDateString()) {
          return ["xdsoft_disabled"]
      }
          if (day.toDateString()===new Date(2014,8,19).toDateString()) {
          return ["xdsoft_disabled"]
      }
          if (day.toDateString()===new Date(2014,8,20).toDateString()) {
          return ["xdsoft_disabled"]
      }
          if (day.toDateString()===new Date(2014,8,23).toDateString()) {
          return ["xdsoft_disabled"]
      }
          if (day.toDateString()===new Date(2014,8,24).toDateString()) {
          return ["xdsoft_disabled"]
      }
          if (day.toDateString()===new Date(2014,8,25).toDateString()) {
          return ["xdsoft_disabled"]
      }
          if (day.toDateString()===new Date(2014,8,26).toDateString()) {
          return ["xdsoft_disabled"]
      }
          if (day.toDateString()===new Date(2014,8,27).toDateString()) {
          return ["xdsoft_disabled"]
      }
            var day = day.getDay();
            if (day == 1 || day == 0) {
                return ["xdsoft_disabled"]
            }
             }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Literal text can be specified in the format string by putting it in single quotes. So try:

```
$("#date").datetimepicker( {
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
    timeFormat: "'at' HH:mm",
    pickerTimeFormat: "HH:mm"
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/g3eh8c0r/14/)

See the documentation of `$.datepicker.formatDate()` in the jQuery UI Datepicker [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

It also says that anything that isn't one of the date format keywords is treated as literal text. Since `at` isn't a keyword, it may work without the quotes:

```
format: "l d-m-Y at H:i"
```

Comment: So far, so good! But now I want to add the Dutch word 'om'. Because 'm' is a date format keyword, it doesn't work. Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: If you put it in quotes it shouldn't matter if it's a keyword.

Comment: If I enter:

format: 'l d-m-Y "om" H:i'
  or
format: "l d-m-Y 'om' H:i"

it returns: Saturday 18-10-2014 'o10' 16:30

Don't get it!

Comment: Where do you see the `format:` option? jQuery UI Datepicker has a `dateFormat:` option, and `Timepicker` adds a `timeFormat:` option. I don't see a way to have them both in a single option. I assumed you were using the [Trent Richardson Timepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)

Comment: There's also no `l` format to show the day of week. I guess you're using a different datetimepicker than I thought.

Comment: I'm using the Jquery Datetimepicker. Downloaded it at jquery.com